# Get the schema from an SqlEntityConnection

Tags: f#, type-providers

I want to fetch information from 1 table (Using OdbcConnection to fetch information) and insert it within a sql server that I connect via the SqlEntityConnection type provider.

I want to do a simple validation where I will compare the columns name and columns type of the tables in both databases. I've been looking around and can't find a way to fetch the columns name and columns type from

```
let EntityConnection = SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionString="...">
```

I am able to fetch information from the table I want but I don't think I can access INFORMATION_SCHEMA, so I'm a little bit loss as to how I can fetch this information.

Thank you.

Comment: If both databases are SQL Server then SQL Server Management Objects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163409.aspx may be of help. However if you don't have permission for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` you probably can't use SMO.